# Change View format in PHP

Tags: views

I have a Drupal 7 site and I would like to change the view format with a button click, so I want to ask if it is a way to change the configuration of a View page with php.

In a view page configuration, the option is this:

[image]

Now it has "List without format" value.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're asking how to changes a view format configuration with PHP code?

Comment: The idea is this: I have a results and two buttons: one button to show the results in a grid and the other to show in a list. Something like this: http://www.vandelaydesign.com/list-grid-view-switch/ but fro Drupal7

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to call a View using PHP code. It is also possible modify a view using code such as `hook_views_pre_view()` to change how a View is displayed dynamically.

I actually wouldn't do either for your request. Simply do the following:

- In your View make 2 `displays`.

  - 1 view display that shows the Grid format.
  - 1 view display that shows the list format.

On the page in question use an HTML button, html link, or even a [Rules Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_link) that uses Ajax to reload the div on the page and calls the view with the correct display mode you want. Your ajax call will be calling like: `$view = views_embed_view('MY_VIEW_NAME', 'display_id');` and updating the page with `$view` contents via Ajax.

So make 2 view displays, and learn how to call them using Ajax.